# Do superfluids have zero viscosity?

Tags: superfluidity

The Wikipedia definition of a super fluid is:

> Superfluidity is a state of matter in which the matter behaves like a fluid with zero viscosity

As a fluid dynamics guy, I have a hard time imagining a zero viscosity fluid. Does superfluids have **near zero viscosity**, or **exactly zero viscosity?** A big of context explaining where the "loss of viscosity" comes from would be great.

Comment: An "electronics guy" might also have trouble imagining a zero resistance conductor, yet superconductors are precisely that. In both cases, the origin of the zero value are quantum effects.

Comment: There are some references here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfluid_helium-4#Theory

Comment: "As a fluid dynamics guy, I have a hard time imagining a zero viscosity fluid": Then don't look at vorticity in superfluids, or you will have an heart attack :-D